# LyX: Different background color for different documents

Tags: color, lyx

By default the background color is RGB = 250, 240, 230.

I want to change the background color for just one particular document (and not for others). (The reason is so I can clearly and quickly distinguish this document from others.)

Is this possible?

(I tried changing the background color for just that one document through Tools > Preferences > Look & Feel > Colors, but it changes it for all documents.)

Comment: Do you want to have multiple documents open at the same time? If not, then you can set up different user directories (with different preferences) and then use the `-userdir dir` argument of `lyx` if you open LyX from the command line.

Comment: @scottkosty: Yes, I want multiple documents open at the same time

Comment: I see. I don't think that's currently possible. You can make an enhancement request at https://www.lyx.org/trac